# Why do square waves have this spectrum response?

Tags: spectrum-analyzer

Below shows my makeshift spectrum analyser, where a 2V, 66Hz square wave on the input. Why do square have have this response (where every harmonic has some amplitude attached to it)? I read somewhere vaguely they have an unlimited spectrum which causes this. The spectrum analyser is using a trapezium window for reference.

[image]

The image below is the input signal on my makeshift oscilloscope.

[image]

Comment: Can your window length be increased? An infinite-length square wave has all odd harmonics, in decreasing magnitude, all the way to infinity. A limited-length square wave will show the same odd harmonics but the spectrum "spreads out" to frequencies around the peaks. Try to identify the location of 3x66 and 5x66, and you will see what I'm talking about, it is not clear whether these frequencies are currently on screen.

Comment: Studying Fourier analysis is the only real answer to this.

Comment: Meet the Square Wave: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACUbBUydgUQ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The images below by [Lucas V. Barbosa](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fourier_transform_time_and_frequency_domains.gif) show the expected transformation from time domain to frequency domain.

[image]

---

[image]

A square wave should produce a series of odd harmonics decreasing in amplitude.

Can you post a 'scope screen grab of the actual "square" wave? I suspect that it isn't quite square.

---

As shown in the update the sides aren't vertical so that's what your analyser is working with. As Vincente points out, if you can zoom out a bit we would expect to see another large spike - but not as tall as the 60 Hz ones at 180 Hz and a weaker one at 300 Hz, etc.

---

[image]

*Figure 3. A typical harmonic analysis display. Source: [PowerSight](http://www.powersight.com/HTML/HOME/Applications.html).*

You might consider a better display layout if you are only interested in power harmonics. These typically show the fundamental as 100% reference and the harmonics as a percentage of that. Notice that the plot of Figure 3 has odd harmonics only and is probably caused by symmetrical wave distortion - possibly caused by rectifiers on a DC supply or switched-mode power supply.

Note that this display shows the fundamental frequency and RMS current at the bottom.

Comment: Posted - does this explain the reason? The scope is not great, by it highlights the data captured such that the sides of the square wave are not perfectly vertical. At least what the data sees anyway.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: @sidA30: And the next update.

Comment: (+1) Wow! That 3D animation is worth a thousands words! Nice find! Next time I'll be explaining Fourier decomposition to my students I'll show it to them, that's for sure.

Comment: It's very good. Make sure you give credit to Lukas V. Barbosa.

Answer (score 0):

These spectral lines are the result of correlation between the input time sequence and the precise mathematics of sinusoidal(cosinusoidal) basis functions used in the Fourier Transform.

Examine the math in the Transform. The behavior is exactly "correlation".

Evaluat the spectral lines for 0.01 second, for 0.1 second, and for 1 second
input time sequence. The shorter time patterns generate less precise correlation output. Why?